# My 64 bit machine can only store 4 bytes each memory location

Tags: c, memory, gdb, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit

My computer is 64bit mac.

How many bytes of information is stored in one of these locations in memory?

When I tried something in gdb

```
x /2x first
0x7ffff661c020: 0xf661b020      0x00007fff
```

My code is

```
#define PUT(p, val) (*((size_t *)(p)) = (val))
PUT(first, (size_t)some pointers);
```

I use gcc -g to compile

It seems that only 4 bytes store in 0x7ffff661c020 . `0x00007fff`stores in 0x7ffff661c024. Why it cant store 0x00007ffff661b020 in 0x7ffff661c020.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Each *memory location* can only store eight bits, because the memory is byte addressable. A 64-bit machine doesn't give you 64 bits in every memory location, it simply means that it can naturally handle 64 bits at a time.

For example, registers are 64 bits wide (unless you intentionally manipulate sub-registers like `ax` or `eax` instead of the 64-bit `rax`), and you can load that many bits from memory with a single instruction.

You can see that it's byte addressable by the fact that your two addresses have a difference of four between them:

```
0x7ffff661c020: 0xf661b020
0x7ffff661c024: 0x00007fff
              \____________/ four-byte
                           \ difference
```

and, if you used byte-based output, you'd see it more "naturally", such as:

```
(gdb) x/8xb first
0x7ffff661c020: 0x20 0xb0 0x61 0xf6 0xff 0x7f 0x00 0x00
```

So the 64-bit value at `0x7ffff661c020` *is* actually `0x00007ffff661b020` as expected, you just need to adjust the `gdb` command to get it out as a full 64-bit values, something like:

```
x/1xg first
```

where `1xg` means one value, hex format, giant word (eight bytes). Details on the `x` command can be found [here](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Memory.html), the important bit for your question is the description of the unit size (my bold):

- `b` = Bytes.
- `h` = Halfwords (two bytes).
- `w` = Words (four bytes). ***This is the initial default.***
- `g` = Giant words (eight bytes).

Comment: Thanks，really helps. I even doubted my code was completely wrong.

Comment: Minor point, there are processors around today that are not "byte addressable", they tend to be embedded processors (eg DSPs) where a barrel roll is a significantly large piece of silicon (multiplied by a thousand processors for example).

Answer (score 3):

> It seems that only 4 bytes store in 0x7ffff661c020

No: you've asked GDB to give you 4 bytes stored at location `0x7ffff661c020`, so that's exactly what it gave you. Try this instead:

```
(gdb) x/gx 0x7ffff661c020
```